# How to extract full images from bbcode?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have a BBCode like this.

```
[IMG]art_74e7e4f8811380426577.jpeg[/IMG] [IMG]art_74e7e4f8811380426595.jpeg[TITLE]title is always needy[/TITLE][/IMG]
```

I need to extract the two images. So my preg_match_all is:

```
preg_match_all('/\[IMG\][^(\[\/IMG\])]+/', $body, $matches);
```

Which gives me this:

```
[0] => [IMG]art_74e7e4f8811380426577.jpeg

[1] => [IMG]art_74e7e4f8811380426595.jpeg
```

I need to include the title tag into the second occurence. Really stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get the image tags as well:

```
preg_match_all('~\[img\].*?\[/img\]~i', $body, $matches);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kP2eA8)

The `i` modifier is for case insensitive matching.

If you don't want to get the image tags, use lookarounds:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=\[img\]).*?(?=\[/img\])~i', $body, $matches);
```

By the way: `[^(\[\/IMG\])]+` will match any character except `(`, `[`, `/`, `I`, `M`, `G`, `]`, `)`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pL0xV9)

`(?<=\[img\])` is a positive lookbehind and makes sure your match has `[img]` before it and

`(?=\[/img\])` is a positive lookahead which makes sure your match has `[/img]` after it. Those don't count as matches so they won't be returned in your capture group.